# bluetooth not installed/working on ubuntu 16.04 on HP envy 15

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, hp

My computer supports Bluetooth on Windows 10, but in **settings>bluetooth**, I cant start bluetooth.

neither `lsmod | grep bluetooth` nor `dmseg | grep bluetooth` returns anything.

I have a `/etc/bluetooth` map with these files in it:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  397 mei 19  2014 input.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3874 sep 28  2015 main.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  120 dec 24  2012 network.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  258 dec 24  2012 proximity.conf
```

if you need any more information to help me I'll be glad to give it.

Comment: If your WiFi card is Ralink corp. RT3290 (wireless + bluetooth), then it had had this bug for a very long time. However, some people managed to activate it (you may find their solutions in the comments of the bug). Here is the link for the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bluetooth/+bug/1189721

Comment: i do have this card, but most of the comments on that link arent usefull or for older versions of ubuntu.